# How to convert a byte literal SNMP response to the expected MAC value

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming, snmp

I'm trying to get the arp table of a cisco switch by using python 3.x and the puresnmp module.

An example of one of the values returned to me when I do a SNMP walk.

```
value_returned = b'\x00!V\x12\x9a\xc1h'
```

I have tried to decode it by using the following:

```
mac = b'\x00!V\x12\x9a\xc1h'
a = mac.decode('UTF-8')
```

But I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 4: invalid start byte
```

How do I convert the value that is returned into a string. Would I convert to a string or into hex?

Comment: Eh? How can you get a byte literal as an SNMP response?

Comment: @EJP I don't know it was just what was returned to me. I'm assuming the snmp module that i'm using is the cause of that. Why are you asking me this question?

Comment: SNMP uses ASN.1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) to transfer data. Is the returned data some sort of ASN.1 data? I tried running it through some ASN.1 decoders but it didn't work. What is giving you that data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue was figuring out how to convert the value returned. I tried several differnt methods but nothing seemed to work.

I finally tried

```
b'L\xccjN\x00\xee'.hex()
```

and that returned the correct value